# How to show ink animation of IconButton without ListTile's ink animation?

Tags: flutter

If you set an IconButton with onPress set to trailing of ListTile with onTap set, both the IconButton ink animation and the ListTile ink animation will be displayed. Is this behavior correct as Material Design?
When I tap the IconButton, I think it is better to show only the Ink animation of IconButton. Is there any way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ListTile` doesn't have `splashColor` and `highlightColor` properties to be modified. One solution to your problem will be removing the `onTap()` function from `ListTile` or setting it to `null`, then wrap `ListTile` with `InkWell` and provide your `onTap` function to it. Then set its `splashColor` and `highlightColor` to `Colors.transparent`:

```
  return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            // here you add the function intended to handle ListTile tap event.
          },
          splashColor: Colors.transparent, 
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: null,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.video_library,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              onPressed: (){},
              splashColor: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            title: Text('Item'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got similiar problem. I found workaround using Stack:

```dart
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
        child: IconButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {},
          iconSize: 16,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );``
```